# desplegar sitio en IIS sin configurar archivo hosts

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

tengo una aplicacion IIS configurada en una red local para desplegar un sitio .net, pero a cada equipo de la red tengo que configurar el archivo hosts para visualizar el sitio, como puedo hacer para que no tenga que configurar el archivo hosts y directamente pueda acceder a mi sitio, si coloco mi ip solo me muestra el logo de IIS pero no muestra mi sitio

estructura de sitio en IIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para acceder a tu sitio deberia de ser algo asi: http://192.168.1.50/NombreDeTuApliacion/Index.html

Comment: @M.Gress no, me dice que no encuentra el archivo

Comment: ¿Desde tu equipo si puedes acceder al sitio como http://localhost/TuAplicacion/TuIndex ?¿

Comment: @M.Gress no tampoco puedo acceder

Comment: ¿Si tienes configurada tu aplicación en IIS?

Comment: si, solo que es una aplicacion mvc, pero no se cual es la carpeta que debo iniciar

Comment: El punto es que es una aplicación web, pero por lo que comentas que ni desde tu maquina tienes acceso, me quisiera suponer que no esta configurada como una aplicación. ¿Podrias compartir una imagen de como esta la estructura de tu IIS ?¿

Comment: @M.Gress ya coloque la imagen con la estructura del sitio

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no tienes configurada ninguna aplicación para ello debes de dar click derecho en Bienvenido y agregar una nueva aplicación le das un nombre y te creara un directorio, y ahi guardas el contenido de tu aplicación y ahora si podrias acceder al sitio con la ip de tu equipo más el nombre de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el link enlaces del menu derecho del IIS, se abre una ventana donde nos pide un nombre de host yo colocaba una ruta www.contoso.com y ahi deberia ir la ip para no tener que configurar en cada pc el archivo hosts, asi de esta forma solo con la direccion ya se puede ingresar al sitio sin tener que hacer la configuracion en cada sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]